# How does Photos know which photos to remove from the device when space is low?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

When using iCloud-hosted Photos, how does the Photos software decide which photos to remove from the device?  Is it just chronological, or based on size, or what?

Also, is there a way to explicitly tell it (like you can with Apple Music) to remove the photo locally but leave the cloud-hosted version in case you want it back on your device later?

Comment: For your second question: iCloud Photos does not delete photos on iCloud, only on your phone.

Comment: @IronCraftMan yes I know - I was asking if there's a way to tell it to remove the photo from my device.